# Getting the same reference variable to an object in other class java

Tags: java, reference, nullpointerexception, initialization

The reason im asking is i am getting Null Pointer Exception.I have one class called as SRSI.java which will parse the image convert into byte array and this byte array i am storing into setter method of another class Account .Now i want this setter value in another 3rd class lets say in action class with the help of getter method.But i am getting NPE.
           //below is the code of SRSI class where i am processing and storing into db and also at same time i am storing into setter method

```
        String fromLocal ="D://1-123456.jpg";
        long accountId = account.getId();
        File file = new File(fromLocal);
        System.out.println("Length--> " + file.length());
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        byte[] bFile= null;
        byte[] imageData = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8192);
            bFile = new byte[8192];
            int count;
            while((count = inputStream.read(bFile))> 0){
                baos.write(bFile, 0, count);
            }
            bFile = baos.toByteArray();
            if(bFile.length > 0){
                imageData = bFile;
            }
            baos.flush();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            //throw ioe;
        }
        //storing the above byte array which contains image into account class setter method here account is reference of account class.
        account.setImageData(imageData);


       //here what account class getter and setter methods looks like
            private byte[] imageData;

           public void setImageData(byte[] imageData){
            if(null!=imageData){
                this.imageData = imageData;
            }
        }

          public byte[] getImageData(){
            return imageData;
          }
         Now what i need this same value in getter method in 3rd class i.e.Action.What i am doing is 
         Action action = new Action();
         action.getImageData();
```

I know by this it will create new object and that why it was returning NPE. But i need the same value of setter into Action class and Action class and SRSI,Account are in different packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign two objects to each other which will make their referents visible to each other eg.

ob = obj;

Answer (score 0):

Your code's a little pseudo-ish, but if I understand you correctly, you just need something like

```
action.setImageData(account.getImageData());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that each instance has its own fields. By coding this is your 3rd class:

```
Action action = new Action();
action.getImageData();
```

This does not give you a reference to the image data of another instance.

Instead you must pass the original Action object to the 3rd class, maybe by creating a `setAction(Action action)` method and saving the Action object passed to it in a field, then using `action.getInageDara()` when you need to.